Coexistence of Bluetooth LE and Classic for Embedded A2DP sink. Android Phone compatibility issue
I am working on an Embedded Audio Product. It is configured as an A2DP sink (Bluetooth Classic). We also use BLE GATT services as a method of control for our companion apps (in-browser with web-bluetooth and native apps).
We use NXP's iMXRT series MCU's, coupled with the IW416 Bluetooth/WiFi SOC for RF comms. This combination of control and audio is working successfully and passing interoperability testing (iOS, Windows, Linux, macOS etc...). However, Android is causing issues. I believe due to the following behaviour:

We MUST advertise BLE as a named connectable service. This enables the app control to work independent of the audio connection
We MUST keep A2DP service connectable so that audio can streamed independent of the control app
The MAC (BD_ADDR) address for both of the bluetooth connections (LE and Classic) is the same. This appears to be a limitation of our hardware, however I am investigating whether it might be possible to set different MACs at PHY layer (or randomize LE).
On Windows (for example) you can clearly distinguish the LE and BT (Audio) connections in the BT settings menu. Helped by a speaker logo to identify the A2DP connection. iOS seems to automatically target A2DP by default... Which works for our implementation.
FAULT CASE: On Android devices, the BLE and BT Classic connections are consolidated into one device. It will always take the name of the LE device (if Classic and LE advertised names are different) and it will always default to connecting to LE control when the User clicks the device in bluetooth settings menu. This means that a user is unable to connect audio from an Android device.

Has anyone experienced this issue before? Is there a standard practice for working around this problem? It feels like we have a lot of unfortunate and incompatible constraints, but I don't think this is too much of a unique use-case. I understand that this design should be permissible (the coexistence of BLE and Classic on the same target device) under bluetooth standards.
I should point out that making the BLE advertisement anonymous helps allow Android Audio connection... except this prevents users from identifying devices with our webBLuetooth control mechanism (i.e. the only thing displayed on connection is LE mac).
Notes:

It seems that a lot of manufacturers (e.g. Sony headphones) Simply keep LE services disabled until Classic Audio is connected. Our UX design does not allow for this
One potential workaround is to randomize the LE address, while maintaining a static Classic BD_ADDR. I am investigating whether this is supported in our hardware.


The solution was to randomize BLE mac. In android bluetooth settings menu, the device now appears as two distinct connections, one A2DP sink and one BLE control. For anyone using the same BT stack (edgefast), you can use the following functions to configure a random BLE MAC:
bt_id_create() // to create a new ID
bt_id_reset()  // to randomize an existing ID

The selected ID (e.g. the one you just created) needs to be set in the advertising parameters when calling bt_le_adv_start(). e.g:
const uint8_t new_id = bt_id_create(<a random mac>, <irk-optional>);

static bt_le_adv_param param[] =
{{.id = new_id, .sid = 0, .secondary_max_skip = 0,
  .options = (BT_LE_ADV_OPT_CONNECTABLE | BT_LE_ADV_OPT_USE_NAME),
  .interval_min = BT_GAP_ADV_FAST_INT_MIN_2,
  .interval_max = BT_GAP_ADV_FAST_INT_MAX_2,
  .peer = NULL }};


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
